# How to add Cron Job on cPanel to execute a PHP files from FTP

Tags: php, magento, cpanel, jobs

I need to run a scraper PHP files daily , So How Can I add Cron-Job? .

There are 3 files which I need to execute daily. and the files are located on my server .

Thanks In advance .

Comment: Have you actually read some tutorials?

Comment: Hi , Biffen thanks for your comment yes its cron and scraper . Sorry for the spelling mistake .

Comment: Try googling for the answer to this instead of posting here.

Answer (score 1):

The basic format of a crontab schedule consists of 6 fields, placed on a single line and separated by spaces, formatted as follows:

minute hour day month day-of-week command-line-to-execute

```
minute hour day month day-of-week command-line-to-execute
```

something like below:

```
0 11 * * * /usr/bin/wget http://www.yourdomain.com/cron.php
```

it will execute daily at 11:00

Comment: You could set this answer to accepted answer! Most welcome @user3494916